# Can I decide which drives will be removed when reducing number of drives in RAID6 array?

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have a RAID 6 array of 7 drives, 4 TB each. I am replacing them one by one with 8 TB drives. I know how to grow my array when all of the drives are replaced. The larger drives have 8 TB partitions, but obviously when they are added to an array with 4 TB drives, only 4 TB of them are used.

I am wondering: is it possible to reduce the number of devices once I replaced only 5 drives?

- 7 drives x 4 TB = 20 TB of RAID 6 array space
- 5 drives x 8 TB = 24 TB of RAID 6 array space

So basically, can I do a

`mdadm --grow --raid-devices=5 /dev/md0`

...with an array that contains 5 drives of 8 TB and 2 drives of 4 TB? Will mdadm know to remove the 4 TB drives from the array and keep only the 8 TB ones?

Maybe the 4 TB drives should have the highest number in the array, so they are "last"?

Or maybe I can fail the 4 TB drives (I have backups, so having no redundancy is OK), and then execute the command above on a degraded array? Will mdadm understand, that I want to have an array with fewer, but larger drives?

Or is there some other way? (I know I can replace all 7 drives with 8 TB ones, and then reduce number of drives, but that requires obtaining two drives just for the array rebuild.)

Comment: Do you have ten slots? If so, build a new array alongside the old. Degrade the old if you have to, in order to gain the slots for the new array

Comment: Do you have only eight slots? If so, fail two disks from your RAID 6 seven, and create a degraded RAID 5 on three new disks. Copy everything across. Pull the old remaining five and keep as a backup of last resort. Add the remaining two new disks and grow the degraded RAID 5 to a full RAID 6. None of this will be fast, and you'll be running on no redundancy during the reshape. Possibly not a great idea for 20TB data

Comment: I have 8 slots. I want to avoid moving data to a new array, if possible.

I could make a 8 TB RAID0 out of two 4TB drives to use it as a temporary additional 8TB partition in the main array, but I'm not sure if it's supported that way.